# How to set a display icon depending on file type- Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, icons, display, file-extension

I'm currently making a web application that enables users to upload their files. Everything is working fine so far. I was asked to add a display icon on the side of the file that was uploaded.

How do I set an image to be displayed when a certain file type is uploaded?

Comment: don't you have to put an icon for that file types in your server? and display it when selected ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an accessor method in your file model like;

```
public function getIconAttribute() {

    $extensions = [
        'jpg' => 'jpeg.png',
        'png' => 'png.png',
        'pdf' => 'pdfdocument.png',
        'doc' => 'wordicon.jpg',
    ];

    return array_get($extensions,$this->extension,'unknown.png');
}
```

The array_get is a laravel helper that looks up a value in an array and can have a third parameter of a default if the extension is not found in the array.

Then in blade you can just icon}}' />

**Or**

A simpler approach where you just make sure to name the icon the same as the extension.

Then in blade you can just extension}}.png' /> and then you don't need to add the accessor at all.

It does not though allow for unknown file types but this might be ok if you are restricting the types of upload (which you should).